# Get current element class list in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to select current element in Vuejs, here's my code:

```
<vs-input label="Password"
          v-model="password"
          danger-text="Wrong password"
          :danger="this.classList.contains('invalid')"/>
```

But `this` is not referring to the current element in Vuejs.

In JavaScript, `this` referred to current element, but things are different here.

I'm wondering how to solve this problem.

Comment: where are you defining `classList`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I want to check if current element has a class name, this is how we got list of classes of current element in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `ref` to that input then use `$refs.input.$el.classList` :

```
   <vs-input label="Password"
          v-model="password"
          danger-text="Wrong password"
          ref="input"
          :danger="$refs.input.$el.classList.contains('invalid')"
          />
```

Comment: I have many inputs in my page, could it be done without using `ref`?

Comment: refs is the vue way to get access to DOM element, if you have many input rendered using `v-for` you could make that dynamic like `:ref="'input'+index"` and `danger="$refs['input'+index].$el.classList.contains('invalid')"`

Comment: I get this error: `Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

Comment: the index should be  defined in v-for like `v-for="(item,index) in items'`

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way then using ref's to lookup if the plugin added a class.

Instead of having a top-level model for every form input `username`, `password` etc make a `form` model which contains `errors` and `values` which encapsulate that form.

Then upon validation, set `this.form.errors[theField]` with the error, then that error will be applied to `:danger-text` and `:danger="form.errors.password"`.

It will also make the error handling from serverside much easier as you simply plop errors back into the model.

For example:

```
data: () => ({
    form: {
      errors: {},
      values: {
        username:'',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.form.errors = {}

      if (!this.form.values.password) {
        this.form.errors.password = 'Password is a required field.'
      } else if (...) {
        ...
      }

      if (Object.keys(this.form.errors).length) return

      // some ajax call
      ajax.post(..).then((res) => {
        if (res.errors) {
          this.form.errors = res.errors
        } else {

        }
      }).catch(e => {
        // maybe set global alert
      })
    }
```

```
<vs-input label="Password" 
          v-model="form.values.password" 
          :danger-text="form.errors.password" 
          :danger="form.errors.password" />
```

Comment: I'm using `vee-validate` for validation, your way is for writing my own validation, so I guess the previous way fits better for me. Thanks though.

Comment: @AlirezaA2F Since you're using `vee-validate`, you should try [`ValidationProvider`](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-provider.html#validation-provider)'s scoped slot, which provides an `invalid` flag that could be bound to your `danger` prop.